# How can I validate a string that contains changing dates and numbers in Minitest?

Tags: ruby, wildcard, string-matching, minitest

Let's say I have a string

```
text = "Date/Time\n19-May-21 10:43:35\nExpires\n19-Jun-2021 13:43\nPrice\n$2.00"
```

How can I validate the string is present while also omitting the dates and price from the string since they are constantly changing?

Ideally I'd like to validate that an integer or datetime is displayed, but the value is not important.

Comment: @stefan - yes, that's my bad. Will update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Some Strategies and High-Level Examples

You have a couple of basic strategies open to you:

1. Use a gem like TimeCop to fix the timestamp of your tests.
2. Use fixture data to test the *logic* of your application, rather than using real (or at least dynamic) data.
3. Use factory data to generate a known value for each test.
4. Test the *format* or *structure* of your result, rather than the specific elements.

As a basic example of the last, we'll assume your data always has the same number of fields and uses `/n` rather than a newline as a delimiter. You might structure your tests to validate:

- The number of fields returned when splitting on `/n` is what you expect.
- The 4th field is a valid Date or DateTime object.
- The 6th or last field contains only `/^\$\d+\.?\d*$/`, or some other validation of the structure or contents of the string.

With these types of tests, you're validating structure rather than specific values, which may be sufficient. If you need to test values, then you need to use a different strategy that allows you to define the expected value ahead of time.